# How can I configure access-control for "destroyAll" of a related model with LoopBack (strongloop)

Tags: acl, strongloop, loopback

I'm using loopback and I have problems with the access control for `destroyAll`, even when I "explicity allow" to `destroyAll` related Models I always get "Authorization required". I maybe just use the wrong name of the function.

For example: I got the User-Model `Human` and `Car`

`Human *hasMany* Cars && Cars *belongsTo* Human`

In human.json I can configure the ACLs with these

```
GET Human/id/Cars --> __get__cars

POST Human/id/Cars --> __create__cars

DELETE Human/id/Cars --> **??? __destroyAll__cars** doesn't work

GET Human/id/Cars/id --> __findById__Cars

PUT Human/id/Cars/id --> __updateById__Cars

DELETE Human/id/Cars/id --> __destroyById__Cars
```

In the ACL it would look like:

```
 {
  "accessType": "EXECUTE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__destroyAll__cars"
}, ...
```

I've tried `deleteAll` too, doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry.. Just found the solution in the minute after posting this question.

It is `__delete__cars`. I think I'd tried this yesterday too. Maybe I had a Typo.